# Importing multiple Flutter modules into Android project

Tags: android, performance, module, flutter

I wonder, if you import several flutter modules, do you have to import their engines(each time, for every module and increase app size) or they can all reference to the same engine(because IT IS the same engine), so we could optimize size of our app?

Engine size is about 3MB at the moment, so if I add 3 flutter modules to my Android app, I would add 9MBs instead of 3.

Any ideas are welcome :)

Comment: its like `import` in java: even if you use it in several classes only one class is shipped with the final apk

Comment: have you tested this?

Comment: You add the module once, and then reference it where needed. It doesn't make a unique copy for every class it's referenced from. You ask if pskink has tested it, but you're in a perfect position to do so. Just reference it in multiple places or one. The app size won't change by more than a few bytes.

Comment: I would even add that only the part of code that you really use is indeed added to your application, the rest is discarded. That's part of the Dart optimization engine and explain why there is no reflection in dart.

Comment: how to add multiple flutter modules to an android project ? can someone please send any reference or example code ? @pskink